# Slim 3 post method returns empty

Tags: php, post, zend-framework, http-post, slim

When I submit a from action to this url, and also test this api via Postman. It is not printing POST data.

But get method is working.

```
$app = new \Slim\App;

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    //"secure"      => false,
    //"relaxed"         => ["localhost", "api.f2f.dev"],
    "header"        => "X-Token",
    "path"          => ["/v2"],
    "passthrough"   => ["/v1/api/token/", "/test", "/v1"],
    "secret"        => getenv("TOKEN_SECRET")
]));

$app->post("/v1/app/register", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
     return $allPostPutVars = $request->getParsedBody();
});
```

I couldn't find the issue i this. But unparsed data is able to print.

Any help is welcome. Any post method on Slim 3 is also welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback should return response object that implements `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface`. It doesn't. So, as an example:

```
$app->post("/v1/app/register", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    $params = $request->getParams();
    return $response->getBody()->write('You have posted '.count($params).' parameters.');
});
```

Sometimes you need a quick and dirty check. Then you can do the following:

```
$app->post("/v1/app/register", function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
    $params = $request->getParams();
    print_r($params);
    die();
});
```

Comment: When I run it gives 1 count for 2 form-data fields. {
    "------WebKitFormBoundaryxYYBVKAVWflZ6OMK\r\nContent-Disposition:_form-data;_name": "\"Store\"\r\n\r\nData I need\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxYYBVKAVWflZ6OMK\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"A\"\r\n\r\nA\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryxYYBVKAVWflZ6OMK--\r\n"
}

Comment: I want the 2 form data to be inserted in db. For this, while I use  $request->getParsedBody(); It returns empty array.

Comment: Any idea @georgy or any code of post method and insertion ?

Comment: @AbelJojo, I'm afraid I won't be able to help, since I don't know the logic/persistence mechanism you've implemented in your application. However, I'll point to simple example of using [Eloquent with Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/cookbook/database-eloquent.html). This might be helpful.

Comment: The code you given as answer works. I will put my code later. No issue.  Thanks a lot.